# In python i have to remove all the same occurance element using remove() in list data type

Tags: python, list

i have wrote a code for deleting same occurrence element remove from list using #remove method

```
l=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
x=int(input("enter the element given in the list:"))#when input is 2
for i in l:
    if i==x:
        l.remove(i)


print(l)
```

but o/p: is coming [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

but all 2 should remove but not removing

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove elements while iterating over a list, the result could be unexpected.

Instead, try assign a new list using list comprehension:

```
l = [x for x in l if x != 2]
```

Or better, use tools like `filterfalse`.